# SPF compliant message with "reply-to" header inside of T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I've got the following T-SQL code below that's working from inside of SQL Server 2005.  I'm looking to add a "reply-to" header so that any reply will go to the "reply-to" address, NOT the FROM address.  Yes, I know about setting this up in Database Mail, but I'm looking to just add some code to my existing solution.  I don't want to use Database Mail.

What I'm looking for is something similar to the following VB code, BUT I WANT A T-SQL VERSION...

```
Dim objMessage
objMessage = Server.CreateObject("CDO.Message")

objMessage.Fields("urn:schemas:mailheader:reply-to").Value = "SOME_OTHER_EMAIL_NOT_FROM"
```

Here's the T-SQL code...

```
EXEC @hr = sp_OACreate 'CDO.Message', @iMsg OUT

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing").Value','2'

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserver").Value','smtp.mymailserver.com'

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername").Value', 'username'

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword").Value', 'password'

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate").Value', '1'

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Configuration.Fields.Update', null

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'To', @To

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'From', @From

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Subject', @Subject

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'TextBody', @Body

EXEC @hr = sp_OAMethod @iMsg, 'Send', NULL
```

I don't understand the syntax to set headers using the T-SQL equivalents.

Comment: why don't you use the built-in mail functionality?

Comment: Many DBA's won;t let you create COM objects on a production server (sp_OACreate)

Comment: Look Mitch, I specifically said that I wasn't looking for a solution with DatabaseMail, yet you obviously didn't read the question well enough.  I AM THE DBA, so I control EVERYTHING.  Please just move on...

Comment: Does the T-SQL code you give work at all? Or you just want to know how to set "reply to"? It isn't clear

Comment: The T-SQL code that I posted works fine, I'm just looking for the "reply-to" header in T-SQL format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EXEC @hr = sp_OASetProperty @iMsg, 'Configuration.fields("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/**senduserreplyemailaddress**").Value', 'search@google.com'

Comment: You f'n rock!  I'm going to try that tomorrow.  You'll get BEST ANSWER if you can tell me where I need to put that in the T-SQL code above.  Specifically, BEFORE or AFTER the "Configuration.Fields.Update" method???

Comment: My guess is before, but just want to make sure.

Comment: Dunno. I can't run sp_OA in my shop... :-)

Comment: I'd say just before, because it's just an attribute like TextBody etc

Answer (score 0):

Use [SQL Server 2005's Database Mail](http://www.sql-server-performance.com/articles/dba/email_functionality_p1.aspx) functionality instead.

Comment: Look Mitch, I specifically said that I wasn't looking for a solution with DatabaseMail, yet you obviously didn't read the question well enough.  I AM THE DBA, so I control EVERYTHING.  Please just move on...